# Convert string with thousands separator to integer?

Tags: python

I have a string which contains some character that I want to remove.

```
a = "2,678"
print int(a.replace(",", ""))
```

Is there a string method instead of function to change that string to integer, something similar to Java's toXXX method.

I want to keep appending methods one after one instead of moving the cursor back to the beginning of the string and put all together.

```
# I like:
a.replace(",", "")....toint()
# I don't like:
int(a.replace(",", "")...)
```

Is there a method for the string class to do what I want?

Comment: There isn't even a method in Java's `String` class to convert to an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing in Python. You can list all of the methods and attributes of a string object by:

```
print dir("")
```

By the way, you can also write this in Java:

```
new Integer("2.3")
```

It is not fair to compare Java's internal type int with Python's int object. In Python, there are no primitive types. Python strings, integers and floats are objects, with methods.

Comment: I am not sure, if you are referring to [primitive data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) in the following sentence: "_In Python, there are no primitive types._".

Comment: Okay, you are right. There are things called primitive data types. However, they are objects with methods and attributes. In Python, a value is an object, and its type is also an object, and its type is also an object etc. From this point of view, Python's "primitive data types" are much like objects in Java.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is the proper way. Per [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

To convert string to integer always do this:

```py
my_integer = int(my_string)
```

You can create your own string-like type (and then use it like that: `my_string = MyString('2678'); my_integer = my_string.to_int()`), but just don't.

In your particular situation of course you need to clean the string from whatever is not really part of the integer - but it depends on your input (have you been thinking about regular expressions, it this is more complex?).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: See last part of my answer. OP asked about string method for converting to integer, I gave the answer. You are right that if `my_string == '2,678'`, my solution won't work. Except I never said that `my_string` is equal to `'2,678'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can derive your own string-like class that behaves the way you want:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.replace(",", ""))
    def to_int(self):
        return int(self)

a = MyStr("2,678")
print int(a)
print a.to_int()
```

Comment: so it inherit all the methods that default str class has and add the to_int method to it?

Comment: That's correct, and it can be used any place a regular string object would be accepted/expected.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're "appending one after one." I think that means the items are part of a larger list...

```
a = '1,000'
b = '2,000'
c = '3,000'

my_list = [a, b, c]
total = 0

for item in my_list:
  item = int(item.replace(',', ''))
  total += item

print total
```

If you're receiving inputs that you need to convert to integers, you only have to set up the replace once.

```
my_input = int(raw_input('Please enter a number: ').replace(',', ''))
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to keep appending methods one by one. It is like mystring.method1().method2()....

Comment: Ahhh... If you're doing that and concerned about bug-checking/readability, just set `a = a.replace(',', ''))` and the next method you apply to a will be on your "new" a.